# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2305 path $.items[0].author

Tags: java, android, json

Hello there I have a little problem here.

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2305 path
>   $.items[0].author

they say the error is here

```
rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s,RSSObject.class);
```

I get json from this url:

```
loadRSSAsync.execute("http://primariagarleni.ro/category/uncategorized/feed/json");
```

I made this script to get json information from my wordpress.

Here is the function that return the infromations:

```
private void loadRSS() {
        AsyncTask<String,String,String> loadRSSAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDialog.setMessage("Asteptati...");
                //mDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String result;
                HTTPDataHandler http = new HTTPDataHandler();
                result = http.GetHTTPData(params[0]);
                Log.v(TAG, "result=" + result);
                Log.v(TAG, "result=" + result);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s,RSSObject.class);

                FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(rssObject,getBaseContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        String RSS_to_Json_API = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";
        StringBuilder url_get_data = new StringBuilder(RSS_to_Json_API);
        String RSS_link;
        RSS_link = "http://primariagarleni.ro/category/uncategorized/feed/atom";
        url_get_data.append(RSS_link);
        loadRSSAsync.execute("http://primariagarleni.ro/category/uncategorized/feed/json");

}
```

This String RSS_to_Json_API = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url="; was the old method, but doesn't work very good because don't update the content on time.

RSSObject class

package com.gireada.garleni;

```
/*
 * Created by Gireada on 8/24/2017.
 */

import java.util.List;


public class RSSObject
{
    public String status;
    public Feed feed;
    public List<Item> items;

    public RSSObject(String status, Feed feed, List<Item> items) {
        this.status = status;
        this.feed = feed;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Feed getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setFeed(Feed feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Item.class

```
package com.gireada.garleni;

/*
 * Created by Gireada on 8/24/2017.
 */

import java.util.List;

public class Item
{
    public String title;
    public String pubDate;
    public String link;
    public String guid;
    public String author;
    public String thumbnail;
    public String description;
    public String content;
    public Object enclosure;
    public List<String> categories;

    public Item(String title, String pubDate, String link, String guid, String author, String thumbnail, String description, String content, Object enclosure, List<String> categories) {
        this.title = title;
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
        this.link = link;
        this.guid = guid;
        this.author = author;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.description = description;
        this.content = content;
        this.enclosure = enclosure;
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Object getEnclosure() {
        return enclosure;
    }

    public void setEnclosure(Object enclosure) {
        this.enclosure = enclosure;
    }

    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<String> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

Comment: `author` is JSONObject instead of JSONArray

Comment: Need more info. What is "s" variable? What is RSSObject class?

Comment: hello there s variable is returned from AsyncTask, i edit my post.

Comment: @Gireada show the code for your Item class.

Comment: @LeoAso i edit my post and put my Item class

Comment: System.out.println(String.format("The s string is : %s", s)); before the line with the error would give some uiseful diagnostic information at the console.

Comment: You declare `author` as a String, but the json is returning something like this: `"author" : { ... }` containing other informations and not just a string!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sdu4wmb5 here is the result. It's http://primariagarleni.ro/category/uncategorized/feed/json this

Comment: @LucaNicoletti i can edit the string and delete the author? What did you think?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti thanks now it's work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as @Luca Nicoletti pointed out, you are using item.author as a String, when it is actually a JSONObject in the API response.

Change Author to a class with a name field and you should be fine.